# Jolt Spec for Shift Operation

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have the following JSON input

```html
{
  "Status": "PENDING",
  "TaskId": "0000000001",
  "EventType": "change",
  "Timestamp": "2019-01-09-15.41.57.473940T01",
  "Comment": "{\"comment\":[{\"createDate\":\"2019-01-09T15:41:57:473000-05:00\",\"type\":\"system\",\"text\":\"Assigned to: RAJ\",\"userId\":\"RAJ\",\"userName\":\"RAJA MADHIE\"},{\"createDate\":\"2019-01-09T15:45:59:150000-05:00\",\"type\":\"manual\",\"text\":\"Comments entered for 0000000001\",\"userId\":\"RAJ\",\"userName\":\"RAJA MADHIE\"},{\"createDate\":\"2019-01-09T15:49:09:586000-05:00\",\"type\":\"manual\",\"text\":\"Comments entered for 0000000001 - processed.\",\"userId\":\"RAJ\",\"userName\":\"RAJA MADHIE\"}]}"
}
```

and expecting the output to be something like:

```html
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "richInput": {
        "subjectId": "0000000001",
        "body": {
          "messageSegments": [
            {
              "type": "system",
              "text": "Assigned to: RAJ"
            }
          ]
        },
        "feedElementType": "FeedItem"
      }
    },
    {
      "richInput": {
        "subjectId": "0000000001",
        "body": {
          "messageSegments": [
            {
              "type": "manual",
              "text": "Comments entered for 0000000001"
            }
          ]
        },
        "feedElementType": "FeedItem"
      }
    },
    {
      "richInput": {
        "subjectId": "0000000001",
        "body": {
          "messageSegments": [
            {
              "type": "manual",
              "text": "Comments entered for 0000000001-processed."
            }
          ]
        },
        "feedElementType": "FeedItem"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried to transform this using couple of JOLT Specs but no luck... Any suggestions or recommendations are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Comment` property is `string` not a `JSON Object`. `JOLT` will not handle case like this. You need to deserialise this `string`, transform and serialise to `JSON`. You can use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) for this.

Comment: @MichałZiober Thanks! is there any other work around other than jackson.

Comment: Can you put here your JOLT specs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make comments a proper JSON structure, it will appear something as below.

```
{
 "Status": "PENDING",
 "TaskId": "0000000001",
 "EventType": "change",
 "Timestamp": "2019-01-09-15.41.57.473940T01",
 "Comment": {
   "comment": [
    {
      "createDate": "2019-01-09T15:41:57:473000-05:00",
      "type": "system",
      "text": "Assigned to: RAJ",
      "userId": "RAJ",
      "userName": "RAJA MADHIE"
    },
    {
      "createDate": "2019-01-09T15:45:59:150000-05:00",
      "type": "manual",
      "text": "Comments entered for 0000000001",
      "userId": "RAJ",
      "userName": "RAJA MADHIE"
    },
    {
      "createDate": "2019-01-09T15:49:09:586000-05:00",
      "type": "manual",
      "text": "Comments entered for 0000000001 - processed.",
      "userId": "RAJ",
      "userName": "RAJA MADHIE"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

Spec file to transform this:

```
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "Comment": {
    "comment": {
      "*": {
        "@(3,TaskId)": "inputs[&1].richInput.subjectId",
        "type": "inputs[&1].richInput.body.messageSegments[0].type",
        "text": "inputs[&1].richInput.body.messageSegments[0].text",
        "#FeedItem": "inputs[&1].richInput.feedElementType"
      }
    }
  }
}
},
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "inputs": {
    "*": {
        "richInput": {
          "subjectId": "inputs[&2].richInput.subjectId",
          "body": "inputs[&2].richInput.body",
          "feedElementType": "inputs[&2].richInput.feedElementType"
         }
       }
     }
   }
  }
]
```